# select a part of vector, summing up to a certain number

Tags: combinatorics

I have a vector of numbers, of the length 24. 
Something like:
[1,5,1,0,5,3.....]
If these would be price tags of goods, and my budget would be 15 dollars,
what is the way to choose all the combinations that are as close to my budget as possible?

Comment: You may find the "knapsack problem" interesting.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: This appears actually to be one of the problems called "subset sum". Like the knapsack problem, it is NP-complete (if the "input size" is taken to be the number of elements of the vector), and a lot has been written about how to solve it quickly in actual practice. More information is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm and https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/classes/lecture8.pdf

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for--any algorithm, or a "good" algorithm (in which case, there's the question about what is "good"). If you want help programming this then the Stackoverflow link I gave above is probably a better place to start looking.